# Error [E0277] in Rust when querying diesel database

Tags: postgresql, rust, compiler-errors, rust-diesel

I am trying to build a simple GraphQL API in rust. However, whenever I build the binary, I get this error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `(Integer, diesel::sql_types::Text, diesel::sql_types::Text, diesel::sql_types::Text, diesel::sql_types::Text, diesel::sql_types::Text, diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Bool>, diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Bool>): load_dsl::private::CompatibleType<User, Pg>` is not satisfied
    --> src\resolvers\users_resolver.rs:11:23
     |
11   |         .load::<User>(connection)
     |          ----         ^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `load_dsl::private::CompatibleType<User, Pg>` is not implemented for `(Integer, diesel::sql_types::Text, diesel::sql_types::Text, diesel::sql_types::Text, diesel::sql_types::Text, diesel::sql_types::Text, diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Bool>, diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Bool>)`
     |          |
     |          required by a bound introduced by this call
     |
     = help: the following other types implement trait `load_dsl::private::CompatibleType<U, DB>`:
               (ST0, ST1)
               (ST0, ST1, ST2)
               (ST0, ST1, ST2, ST3)
               (ST0, ST1, ST2, ST3, ST4)
               (ST0, ST1, ST2, ST3, ST4, ST5)
               (ST0, ST1, ST2, ST3, ST4, ST5, ST6)
               (ST0, ST1, ST2, ST3, ST4, ST5, ST6, ST7)
               (ST0, ST1, ST2, ST3, ST4, ST5, ST6, ST7, ST8)
             and 24 others
     = note: required for `SelectStatement<FromClause<table>, DefaultSelectClause<FromClause<table>>, NoDistinctClause, ..., ..., ...>` to implement `LoadQuery<'_, _, User>`
     = note: the full type name has been written to 'D:\Documents\chat\server\target\debug\deps\server.long-type-9800167139566061747.txt'
note: required by a bound in `diesel::RunQueryDsl::load`
    --> C:\Users\cooke\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\diesel-2.0.4\src\query_dsl\mod.rs:1499:15
     |
1499 |         Self: LoadQuery<'query, Conn, U>,
     |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `RunQueryDsl::load`
```

The function that is making the error is this:

```
pub fn get_users() -> Vec<User> {
    use crate::schema::users::dsl::*;
    let connection = &mut establish_connection();
    let results = users
        .limit(5)
        .load::<User>(connection)
        .expect("Error loading posts");
    results
}
```

My user model is like this:

```
#[derive(Queryable)]
pub struct User {
    pub id: i32,
    pub first_name: String,
    pub last_name: String,
    pub email: String,
    pub password: String,
    pub phone: String,
    pub active: bool,
    pub superuser: bool,
}
```

I also have an `impl User` for the getters that I have omitted here to keep it succinct.
I have tried creating another rust crate with exactly the same function, just with a stripped-down user model and that works perfectly. How can I resolve the error? My database is PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error indicates a mismatch between what your query returns and what your struct expects the query to return. The fields returned by your query and those in your struct need to match by count, order and type.

In your case the issue is that both the `active` and the `superuser` field are considered to be nullable in your query return type. That means you need to use `Option<bool>` as field type there.